# How to share dependencies between IFrames using Module Federation?

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

How can i share library dependencies (react) between 1 app (host) and a iFrame. Both the host application and the iFrame are in the same domain, so they can access global window objects from one another.

According to the author its possible if "you can create a global object between the two".

But i was not able to achieve this. I'm not sure at what "global object" the Module Federation author is referring to. I have also tried to look into this [article](https://scriptedalchemy.medium.com/understanding-webpack-module-federation-a-deep-dive-efe5c55bf366), but wasn't succeeded either.

I know this is not the usual case to use module federation but, any input on how to achieve this is valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe, in general, is another page inside your page, that has its own HTML, CSS, and JS.

Module federation is an approach where a piece of JS is loaded inside your main page dynamically and then executed with the mount() (or similar) method.

That being said, sharing code between an iframe and its parent looks impossible, or at least not recommended, the idea is to have an isolated container.

If you are worried about downloading things twice, rest assured that the browser will cache JS files that are requested more than once regardless of who requests them: iframe or parent: [Possible to share javascript imports across iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348512/possible-to-share-javascript-imports-across-iframes)

If you want to really have a direct call from the parent to the iframe, this article claims you can: https://medium.com/@thinuwanwickramaarachchi/communication-between-iframe-and-its-parent-app-ed39ba65cde1

Again I cannot recommend this as the iframe's goal is isolation. You can take a look at how to communicate without breaking the isolation here: [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)